# Best Pythonic way to store variables inside a class

Tags: python

Here are 4 different ways of storing variables. I'm trying to see which way is most Pythonic way in a sense that it is easy to read.

Maybe, creating an external file and place all the variables in there might be helpful? I don't care much about people being able to access these variables into other files. The variables will only be used for this class.

---

Defining the variables inside the methods.

```
class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self, color, breed, age):
        self.color = color
        self.breed = breed
        self.age = age

    def is_old_cat(self):
        OLD_AGE = 15

        if self.age > OLD_AGE:
            return True

        return False

    def is_young_cat(self):
        YOUNG_AGE = 5

        if self.age < YOUNG_AGE:
            return True

        return False

    def is_medium_young(self):
        LOW_MEDIUM_AGE = 8
        HIGH_MEDIUM_AGE = 12

        if LOW_MEDIUM_AGE < self.age < HIGH_MEDIUM_AGE:
            return True

        return False
```

---

Inside the class.

```
class Cat(object):
    OLD_AGE = 15
    YOUNG_AGE = 5
    LOW_MEDIUM_AGE = 8
    HIGH_MEDIUM_AGE = 12

    def __init__(self, color, breed, age):
        self.color = color
        self.breed = breed
        self.age = age

    def is_old_cat(self):
        if self.age > self.AGES['OLD_AGE']:
            return True

        return False

    def is_young_cat(self):
        if self.age < self.AGES['YOUNG_AGE']:
            return True

        return False

    def is_medium_young(self):
        if self.AGES['LOW_MEDIUM_AGE'] < self.age < self.AGES['HIGH_MEDIUM_AGE']:
            return True

        return False
```

---

Outside the class.

```
OLD_AGE = 15
YOUNG_AGE = 5
LOW_MEDIUM_AGE = 8
HIGH_MEDIUM_AGE = 12


class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self, color, breed, age):
        self.color = color
        self.breed = breed
        self.age = age

    def is_old_cat(self):
        if self.age > AGES['OLD_AGE']:
            return True

        return False

    def is_young_cat(self):
        if self.age < AGES['YOUNG_AGE']:
            return True

        return False

    def is_medium_young(self):
        if AGES['LOW_MEDIUM_AGE'] < self.age < AGES['HIGH_MEDIUM_AGE']:
            return True

        return False
```

---

Inside another class.

```
class Ages:
    OLD_AGE = 15
    YOUNG_AGE = 5
    LOW_MEDIUM_AGE = 8
    HIGH_MEDIUM_AGE = 12


class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self, color, breed, age):
        self.color = color
        self.breed = breed
        self.age = age

    def is_old_cat(self):
        if self.age > Ages.OLD_AGE:
            return True

        return False

    def is_young_cat(self):
        if self.age < Ages.YOUNG_AGE:
            return True

        return False

    def is_medium_young(self):
        if Ages.LOW_MEDIUM_AGE < self.age < Ages.HIGH_MEDIUM_AGE:
            return True

        return False
```

Comment: In first code snippet you actually have no class variables, you have only local variables in uppercase

Comment: I'd use an `enum` or even just global variables here.

Comment: The best way to store constants widely used in different files - store in separate file. But if you use them only in current file, it is normal to put them just in a head of file, before they've been used

Comment: Also, return self.age < self.YOUNG_AGE looks way more pythonic than your if x return True (else) return False

Comment: @RomanAnderson When you say the head of the file, do you mean outside the class or inside the class, above the __init__ method?

Comment: @Anthony, it depends on what is the scope of usage of the variable. If you need var only in class - then use it in the class. If file will contain more then one class, uses this constant - put it outside the class in the head of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this that I see the most... Are they the most Pythonic? Not sure, so I will leave up to the true python ninjas and not make any bold statements about that.

If these values are specific to cats, you can get away with this.

```py
class Cat(object):
    OLD_AGE = 15
    YOUNG_AGE = 5
    LOW_MEDIUM_AGE = 8
    HIGH_MEDIUM_AGE = 12

    def __init__(self, color, breed, age):
        self.color = color
        self.breed = breed
        self.age = age

    def is_old_cat(self):
        if self.age > self.OLD_AGE:
            return True

        return False
```

The other way is to make an enum that you can reuse in places outside of your `Cat` class. Many will say this is the better method.

However, if you do choose to use an enum it may be confusing if you had a `Human` class where you would want to be clear that 15 is old for cats, not for humans.

```py
from enum import IntEnum
class Age(IntEnum):
    OLD = 15
    YOUNG = 5
    LOW_MEDIUM = 8
    HIGH_MEDIUM = 12

print(Age.OLD) # 15
print(Age.YOUNG) # 5
```

Comment: you can add the language after the three backticks in the markup so as to trigger syntax color: `'''python` (where `'` should be a backtick, but it's already wrapped in backticks so...)

Comment: `Enum` is the best answer. That's the whole point of it, and it works well with type hinting. Class variables don't make sense here.

Comment: @Rightleg thanks for the edit... I'm always lazy about adding syntax highlighting in my coding blocks lol

Comment: These two approaches are very different from a semantic standpoint: the second has actually nothing to do with class variables. If I see something defined outside of a class, then I expect it to be used somewhere else than in this class; else there's no use to give it that scope. Class variables (or actually more often, class constants) convey the meaning that they define a property of the class, that can be inherited, or have different values for sibling classes; top level enums or whatever kind of global variables are the same for all classes, whether or not they share inheritance links.

Comment: @Rightleg I totally agree. I was actually trying to convey that but it came out wrong. I made some edits to make it more clear that an enum shouldn't be only relevant to a single class. Thanks again for the heads up.

Comment: Enums are not comparable to integers. Trying so will raise a `TypeError`. An `IntEnum` however, is working correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Wombatz. Totally forgot about that when writng this. Made an edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the enums in this file only, have them be in the same file. Else, move them to a different file.